# How to use bindingsource.filter using a var?

Tags: c#, linq, bindingsource

I have a query that takes the first and last name from text boxes and I get a var.  This works if I want to change the datasource but that does not help me much as it breaks a lot of code doing it that way.  I would prefer to use .filter.  How can I use .filter in this case?  Note that the .filter = results does not function and the reason why is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

```
private void btnSrchInterests_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var results = from c in db.CaseSelectors
                          join i in db.Interests on c.CaseNumberKey equals i.CaseNumberKey
                          where i.First.Contains(txtFirst.Text) && i.Last.Contains(txtLast.Text)
                          select c;

            caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = results;                              

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `results` is currently a `System.Linq.IQueryable` and thus cannot be cast to a string, as expected by the property `Filter`.

If the type of `db.CaseSelectors` is a `IList<String>` you can do the following

```
caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = results.Single()
```

note tht this execute the linq query and return only a single string (and the query can only return one item).

If the type of `db.CaseSelectors` is a `IList<ComplexType>` you can do the following

```
caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = results.Single().YourFilterProperty;
```

Where `YourFilterProperty` is the property that contains the string with the filter

If your query returns a multiple items, you do a `results.First()` or iterate list to construct your filter.

**Edit**

After debating, the full answer is:

```
    private void btnSrchInterests_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var results = from c in db.CaseSelectors
                      join i in db.Interests on c.CaseNumberKey equals i.CaseNumberKey
                      where i.First.Contains(txtFirst.Text) && i.Last.Contains(txtLast.Text)
                      select c.CaseNumberKey;

        caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = ("CaseNumberKey =" + String.Join(" OR CaseNumber = ", results.ToList()) );
    }
```

Comment: Can I convert db.CaseSelectors to an IList?  It would appear that would be what I have to do.  Never have used IList before.

Comment: If you want a plain list you can do `results.ToList()` this is probably what you're most used to work it. But soon, as you understand Linq, you'll probably see that there are a few other methods to help you along the way.

Comment: If I convert it to a list I am still getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'CityCollectionCSharp.CaseSelector' to 'string'"

Comment: Please post the class definition of the  `CityCollectionCSharp.CaseSelector`

Comment: CityCollectionsCSharp.CaseSelector is a SQL database.table that is part of DataClasses1DataContext.  Not sure what else you would want?

Comment: `CaseSelectors` should be some like `DbSet<Something>` can you give me the class definition of the `Something`? Just do, on Visual Studio, "Go Definition" to the `Caseselector`, and do again "Go Definiton" to Something on the `DbSet<Something>`. Dump the `public class Something` definition. You should see the CaseNumberKey property and probably more properties. Which one has the criteria that you want to set as the filter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32970/discussion-between-korrowan-and-saamorim)